# Is WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter of Spring Security Framework an example of Adapter Design Pattern?

Tags: spring, design-patterns

I was reading through the Adapter design pattern and also came across the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` of Spring Security framework and I wanted to know if they both can be related somehow. Especially considering the fact that the class name ends with `Adapter`.
This will definitely strengthen my design patterns knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

In my view `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` can't be considered an example of the GoF Adapter pattern. This is an accepted definition of this pattern:

> The adapter pattern is a design pattern that is used to allow two
>   incompatible types to communicate. Where one class relies upon a
>   specific interface that is not implemented by another class, the
>   adapter acts as a translator between the two types.

That is to say, we have an interface that needs to be used by a client but the interface is not compatible, so an adaptation needs to be done. The Adapter holds a reference to the Adaptee to transalate its operations for the client:

[image: Adapter Pattern]

Now, going back to Spring's `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, this is what its Javadoc states:

> Provides a convenient base class for creating a {@link
>   WebSecurityConfigurer} instance. The implementation allows
>   customization by overriding methods.

So despite being called Adapter, it is actually a kind of builder that allows you to customize different aspects of web security.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. The explanation quite clears my doubt.